# Inheritance with Scala 'object'

Tags: java, scala, object

I have this Java code:

```
class Super {
    public static void foo() { bar(); }
    public static void bar() { out.println("BAR");}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        foo();
    }
}
class Sub extends Super {
    public static void bar() { out.println("bar"); }
}
```

And I would like to see what it does in Scala, but can't seem to find how to write the equivalent. This is what I have:

```
object Super  {
  def foo() { bar() }
  def bar() { println("BAR")}
  def main( args : Array[String]) {
    foo()
  }
}
object Sub extends Super {
  override def bar() { println("bar")}
}
```

But doesn't compile. It is because object can't inherit ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You might want to change it into something like this

```
class Super {
  def foo() { bar() }
  def bar() { println("BAR")}
  def main( args : Array[String]) {
    foo()
  }
}

object Super extends Super {
}

object Sub extends Super {
  override def bar() { println("bar")}
}
```

This way you have both the type Super and the object Super.

EDIT : Just moved the main method to class Super, that way it is cleaner.

Comment: Ok, that worked. I had to re-write the main method though. Thanks. http://pastebin.com/p7zudCdf

Comment: @OscarRyz Put `main` in the class as well.

Comment: Is this a hack?

Answer (score 4):

You can only extend from classes. So you might wanna change `Super` to be a `class` instead of an `object`

Also, you need to add the `override` keyword to the method you plan to override.

See "Method Overriding" [here](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/scala-for-java-refugees-part-3)

Comment: I've got: `error: not found: type Super:
object Sub extends Super  {`

Comment: Oh yes sorry. You would eventually meet the error I mentioned though. Let me edit the answer

Comment: [This nabble post gives some reasoning for not being able to extend objects](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Possible-makes-sense-to-extend-an-object-td1938670.html)

Comment: I added: `class Super` and now the message is: error: `method bar overrides nothing :
override def bar() { println("bar")}`

Comment: I get from pst link it not possible to inherit things in object... am I right?

Comment: When you add the Super class, move also related method declarations. See my answer for an example solution.