# Scala - Singleton Object inheritance

Tags: scala

I have a working `Scala` application in production that is using a `object` which has several methods defined inside it.

There are new requirements for this application where I will have to rewrite (override) few of the methods from that `object` while reusing the definitions of remaining methods from that `object`.

How can I create a new `object` inheriting the original one so that I can override the definitions of a few selected methods?

Comment: Seems like this has been asked before e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256015/inheritance-with-scala-object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Scala `object` cannot inherit from another Scala `object` so the obvious way is not possible.

If you can modify the original `object` then create a class that implements all the functionality and make the original `object` inherit from that class. Your new object can then inherit from the same class and override the methods that you want to change. However this will create two copies of any values in the base class, so it is not suitable for an `object` that contains a lot of data or does any one-off initialisation.

If you cannot modify the original `object` then you will have to copy all the methods of the first `object` in your new `object`. `val`s can be copied directly. `defs` can be copied using eta expansion:

```
def v = Original.v    // This is a simple value
def f = Original.f _  // This is a function value
```

Using `def` rather than `val` here will avoid storing multiple copies of the original values and will prevent lazy values from being computed until they are needed.

Using eta expansion will make `f` a function value rather than a method which may or may not be a problem depending on how it is used. If you require `f` to be a method then you will have to duplicate the function signature and call the original f:

```
def f(i: Int) = Original.f(i) // This is a method
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tim ! Modifying original object to move functionality into a class or trait is not an option for me as it is a live application in production and I do not want to touch and retest the live functionality.  Copying vals using defs and methods using eta expansion sounds to be a very good idea for my situation. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to move the code/logic to a `trait` or `abstract class` and have both `objects` extend these.

On the upside this would also give you better testability.

Another more hacky approach could be to not use the class/type system at all and jsut forward the methods using a new singleton objec:

```
scala> object A {def foo: String = "foo" ; def bar:Int = 0}
defined object A

scala> object B { def foo = A.foo; def bar = "my new impl" }
defined object B

scala> A.foo
res3: String = foo

scala> B.foo
res4: String = foo

scala> A.bar
res5: Int = 0

scala> B.bar
res6: String = my new impl
```

Comment: Thank you so much Andreas! Your hacky approach sounds good and will work for my situation as I can not modify the existing object (live in production) to inherit from a trait.